# Set pagination off while searching documents in marklogic for a specified criteria

Tags: java, marklogic

I am doing a search in the marklogic using JsonDocumentManager by providing the StructuredQuery Definition. As a result I am getting a DocumentPage, defaults to 50 records (page length defaulted in JsonDocumentManager). But I want to retrieve all the documents in one go?

I can see two options here to solve this, either by increasing the page length to a limit which cannot be exceeded for the criteria I am supplying or by providing the page offset in the `jsonDocumentManager.search(queryDefinition, pageOffset)` in the loop till the documentPage.isLastPage returns to true

Could some one please let me know the further options if any? Is there any parameter for pagination which I can switch to false to not allow marklogic to do a paginated search?

Comment: It is usually unwise to pull in all docs in one request, unless you are sure there is only a limited number, like less than 500. For anything beyond that, it is usually wisest to run requests in parallel or iterate over the pages in sequence. Can you elaborate on the purpose?

Comment: Thanks grtjn for the reply.  My use case is.. I want to create the csv file by fetching all the documents from the database which passes the specified search criteria.  Expected volume is around 70k per day..  So either I can increase the page size but as suggested by you it's not a good approach or I can supply the page offsets in search in a loop.  Could you please let me know the recommended approach I should follow??

Comment: 70k is very big, but not too big for a single page, assuming you can get everything back from the server within your configured request timeout.  However, you may find that paginating in a loop works better since it allows the server to allocate memory to smaller requests instead of one massive request.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @grtjn, it's always best to paginate, and even faster if you can run requests in parallel.  For that reason, the Java API doesn't have a flag to get all results.  Nor do the layers it builds on: REST API and the search:search API.

The layer those build on, cts:search, uses server-side lazy evaluation to efficiently paginate under the hood while it appears to get all results. With that said, if you must have another options besides those you already know about, consider creating a [Resource extension](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_27702) and have it call directly to the cts:search API.

For what it's worth, in MarkLogic 9 we'll be providing the [Data Movement SDK](https://ea.marklogic.com/features/data-integration/data-movement-sdk/) which will do all the pagination and parallelization for you under the hood on the client side.  It is specifically designed for long-running data movement applications that need to export or manipulate large datasets.  If that's of interest, please consider joining the early access program and you can try it out.

Comment: Thanks Sam... I will try with resource extension.. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi Sam, I tried using the resource Extension. I have one question though... Earlier using the jsonDocManager.search(....), I was getting the DocumentPage and then iterating over it returns me the DocumentRecord which helps me get the documentUri  and document metadata using DocumentMetadataHandle. Can we get the document metadata and document uri in this case? I guess using the javascript and returning the object that consists of document uri, document metadata and document content would be the way I can follow. Then I can make of resource extension to get this object and then work acordingly?

Comment: Correct, you can return a custom XML or JSON payload that contains all the information you need.  However, I'd recommend either paginating in a loop or just increasing the page size instead of going to all this work creating a custom extension.